# LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient not init and cause System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am a newbie to ASP MVC. When I using the LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient to check the
user info, I meet a problem about the class construct error. The error message shows "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException", and the state of LoginWebServiceSoapClient is Faulted.

the following is my code Snippet:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Logon(LoginInfo data)
{
    LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient client = new LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient();
    client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    .....
}
```

And the setting of the web.config is as belowed:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ExampleWeb" loginUrl="~/Account/Login/" timeout="120" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
  
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LoginWebServiceSoap">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="LoginWebServiceSoap1" />
        <binding name="LoginWebServiceSoap2">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="LoginWebServiceSoap3" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https:XXXXXXXXXXX.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LoginWebServiceSoap2"
        contract="LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoap" name="LoginWebServiceSoap1" />
    </client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Is there any instruction for this, and how to fix that,and why it happening in this way?
Any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussions, the situation is solved via delete and rebuild Web Service,
and furthermore, not setting breakpoint on the code:

```
  LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient client = new LOGINSERVICE.LoginWebServiceSoapClient();
```

My environment is Visul Studio 2019, and if the run into debug mode and stop on the breakpoint on the upper code snippet, the connection state wii be Faulted.
That's all I got. Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks.